# JavaScript make object to array only by messageid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

Let's say I have the following:

```
  [
 { messageid: '582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7b43',
        _id: 582b4c79105387dd21e08004 } ,
 { messageid: '582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7xb43',
        _id: 582b4c79105387dd21e08s004 } 

]
```

How can I make it produce a array that would only be the `messageid` `s values?

Like:

`{582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7b43,582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7xb43}` ?

Note: plain javascript or angular

Comment: You need an array or object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var output = input.map(function(item) {
  return item.messageid;
});
```

This will create an array that will look like `[582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7b43,582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7xb43]`

Answer (score 2):

You could map the property `messageid`.

```js
var objectArray = [{ messageid: '582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7b43', _id: '582b4c79105387dd21e08004' }, { messageid: '582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7xb43', _id: '582b4c79105387dd21e08s004' }],
    newArray = objectArray.map(function (o) {
        return o.messageid;
    });

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` to loop through the array

```
var orArray = [{
        messageid: '582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7b43',
        _id: '582b4c79105387dd21e08004'
      }, {
        messageid: '582b4350af7cb8f21e4b7xb43',
        _id: '582b4c79105387dd21e08s004'
      }

    ];

    var newArr = [];
    orArray.forEach(function(item) {
      newArr.push(item.messageid)
    });
    console.log(newArr)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/f885rah6/)